# How to supress "Couldn't open app window is the pop-up blocker enabled?" error on IE 10 in selenium

Tags: selenium

When am trying to launch any website using selenium RC, it is showing below error message
"Couldn't open app window is the pop-up blocker enabled?"

Am using Windows 8(64bit machine) with IE 10 installed.

To suppress this error I tried following steps and run my script.
1. In Internet Options -> Security -> Uncheck the Enable protected Mode" for all 4 zones.
2. Under Tools -> Pop Up-Blocker -> Turn Off pop up blocker

Even after doing the above two steps it is showing the same error for me.
Could some one please let me know what else I can do to suppress this error message.

Comment: Please some one help me how to come up with the error message mentioned in IE10 (Am using windows8 64bit machine).